# Why does the date change when a time is set?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am curious as to why when I set the Time(i.e. hour, minute, and seconds) the date subtracts one. e.g. for this code

```
Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarStart.setTime(startDate);
calendarStart.set(11, 0);
calendarStart.set(12, 0);
calendarStart.set(13, 0);
calendarEnd.setTime(endDate);
calendarEnd.set(11, 23);
calendarEnd.set(12, 59);
calendarEnd.set(13, 59);
```

or even this code

```
startDate.setHours(0);
startDate.setMinutes(0);
startDate.setSeconds(0);
endDate.setHours(23);
endDate.setMinutes(59);
endDate.setSeconds(59);
```

Let's say I have the start date of `August 01, 2018` and a end date of `August 07, 2018` and after I set the above values the dates that come out are `Tue July 31 00:00:00 CDT 2018` and a end date of `Mon August 06 23:59:59 CDT 2018`. Why does this happen and what way around can I take besides just adding a day to it after it is set.

**Instantiating Start and End:**

```
endDate = new Date();
Calendar temp = Calendar.getInstance();
temp.add(Calendar.DATE, -90);
startDate = new Date(temp.getTimeInMillis());
```

When this is initialized, it works fine but it's as soon as the values are set then it subtracts a day. I have it print  the value before and after setting the values. Before it is as expected but as soon as it sets those value then it subtracts the day.

Comment: Please show the code on how you instantiate `startDate` and `endDate`

Comment: @Ascalonian it's been updated

Comment: The code you've shown to instantiate `startDate` and `endDate` does NOT set them to August 1 and August 7.  How are you _really_ instantiating them?

Comment: `Calendar` is, and always was, a broken class. Use the modern classes from the `java.time` package.

Comment: Bohemian's suggestion is good. But using the Calendar object directly is going to get you into trouble, and you're better with GregorianCalendar than Calendar. However, the new classes in java.time are a MUCH better choice.

Comment: Voting to close as not enough source code has been shared to make a diagnosis.

Comment: Are `startDate` and `endDate` instances of `java.util.Date`? The `setXxx` methods are deprecated because they are unreliable, so under no circumstances use those. There’s no point whatsoever. For a start date and an end date use two `LocalDate` variables. A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day so will save you of the issue you are having.

Comment: When running your code just now I got `Thu May 10 00:00:00 CDT 2018` and `Wed Aug 08 23:59:59 CDT 2018`. I see no issue apart from the use of the long outdated and poorly designed date and time classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### LocalDate from java.time

```
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.AUGUST, 1);
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.AUGUST, 7);
    System.out.println("Start is " + start + ". End is " + end + '.');
```

> Start is 2018-08-01. End is 2018-08-07.

The `LocalDate` class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, represents a date without time of day. So you don’t need to set the time (you also cannot), so there could never be any issue of potential side effects of doing so.

### What went wrong in your code?

I seriously doubt that the code you have posted behaves the way you describe. Hence I think that your bug is somewhere else. Without [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is not possible to be sure, though.